# Выражение "то бишь"

Tags: этимология

"То бишь" значит - "то есть". Но откуда взялось это "бишь", что оно означает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Фасмера частица БИШЬ объясняется как аллегровая (сокращенная) форма *баешь* от *баю* "говорю".